# Fourier transformation of complex exponential proof

Tags: fourier-analysis

How do I prove that the Fourier transformation of the complex exponential

$$\exp\left[ i  \pi(( a^2  x^2) +(b^2 y^2))\right]$$
 is 
$$\exp\left[i {\pi}\left( {fx^2 \over a^2} + {fy^2 \over b^2}\right)\right]$$

Comment: Please write your expression in Latex.

Comment: What is your $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Careful analysis of the Cauchy principle value integral for the Fourier transform gives
$$
\begin{align}
   &\mbox{c.p.v.}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\pi a^{2}x^{2}}e^{-ixs}dx \\
   & = \mbox{c.p.v.}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\pi(ax-s/2\pi a)^{2}}dx\, e^{-is^{2}/4\pi a^{2}} \\
  & = \left(\mbox{c.p.v.}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\pi a^{2}x^{2}}dx\right)e^{-ia^{2}s^{2}/4\pi} = Ce^{-is^{2}/4\pi a^{2}}.
\end{align}
$$
The constant $C$ comes from a [Fresnel integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) , at least after a linear change of variable.
$$
             C=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}cos(\pi a^{2} x^{2})dx.
$$